# Is there a way to listen for keypresses without a Context?

Tags: android

I have been given an API by a vendor that constructs an object that I provide that is intended to listen for hardware button keypresses, something like:

```
interface ButtonListener {
    void onButton(String buttonName);
}

interface ButtonApi {
    void addListener(ButtonListener);
}

class MyButtonApi implements {
    ButtonListener listener;

    public void addListener(ButtonListener listener) {
        listener = listener;
    }

    public void whatCallsThisMethod(void) {
        listener.onButton("a button");
    }
}
```

Once the `MyButtonApi` object has been constructed any hardware button presses should result in the listener `onButton` method being called.

So the problem I have is I can't think of a way to listen for buttons in the created object as I have no reference to a Context (or Activity or Service, basically no objects beyond the listener).

Is there a way to listen to button presses in this situation?

Ways I could think of:

- Activity `onKey` methods - not possible, I have no activity
- Intents - not possible AFAIK as I would need a Context to create a BroadcastReceiver
- Binder - again I believe I need a Context in order to bind or be binded to

Are there any other ways I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

So just give context for your API class:

```
class MyButtonApi {
    public MyButtonApi(Context context, ButtonListener listener);
}
```

Comment: This would be a perfect solution, however this API is not defined by me it is defined by a vendor and I cannot change it (well, I've sent a message to the vendor but it is not likely changeable).

Comment: I've edited the code to hopefully make it clearer. I'm given a listener to call when a button press happens, but I am interested in figuring out how I can detect button presses without a Context (given the API I am conforming to does not provide one).

Comment: @WillNewton i gave you another answer, pls check, i think you don't need context

Answer (score 0):

if I understood you right the third time, you trying to get some key pressing via another API(not android);
so I can assume next approach:

```
class MyActivity implements ButtonListener {
    MyButtonApi api = new MyButtonApi(this);
    List<String> buttonEvents = new ArrayList();
    @Override
    void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        api.whatCallsThisMethod();            
    }
    @Override
    void onButton(String buttonName) {
        buttonEvents.add(buttonName);
    }
}

//So now you have buttons that were pressed, i think you don't need context in this case
```

Comment: I need to get the button press from somewhere though (e.g. some kind of IPC or access to an underlying device), that is my problem.

Comment: Can you share some more info? How you access to API object? Where you create it? For handling event from API you just need implement ButtonListener, so class with ButtonListener interface can get access to buttonName varialbe.

Comment: The button listener object is implemented by the owner of the API and passed in on object construction. I am given a single class to implement (MyButtonApi) that must listen for button presses and pass them to the listener.

Comment: Unfortunately I think the code example is adding confusion here, so I will have to think about a better way to ask this question.